# Define a macro for OpenMPI 1.3

Tags: autoconf, openmpi

I am trying out very old version of OpenMPI [1.3](https://svn.open-mpi.org/trac/ompi/browser/trunk?rev=13875).

I could run `autogen.sh` to generate `configure`. But while running `make` I have following error:

```
In file included from event.c:37:0:
../../opal/event/compat/sys/_time.h:47:8: error: redefinition of 'struct timeval'
 struct timeval {
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h:45:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:219,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314,
                 from ../../opal/include/opal_config_bottom.h:372,
                 from ../../opal/include/opal_config.h:1341,
                 from event.c:28:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/time.h:30:8: note: originally defined here
 struct timeval
        ^
In file included from event.c:37:0:
../../opal/event/compat/sys/_time.h:55:8: error: redefinition of 'struct timespec'
 struct timespec {
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:219,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314,
                 from ../../opal/include/opal_config_bottom.h:372,
                 from ../../opal/include/opal_config.h:1341,
                 from event.c:28:
/usr/include/time.h:120:8: note: originally defined here
 struct timespec
        ^
```

I check the file which includes the header `_time.h` with `ack`. For instance the file `opal/event/event.c` includes that header. It has the following lines:

```
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_TIME_H
#include <sys/time.h>
#else
#include <sys/_time.h>
#endif
```

So it looks like I need to define the macro HAVE_SYS_TIME_H throughout the whole project to migrate the issue. How to do that?

UPDATE: I just notice that `sys/time.h` exits in `/usr/include/linux/time.h`. Does `sys` map to `linux` dir?

PS: Running `autoreconf -i` has the following error:

```
$ autoreconf -i
aclocal: error: acinclude.m4:111: file 'config/mca_no_configure_components.m4' does not exist
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

I created some missing files and reran `autoreconf -i`, I then got following error:

```
$ autoreconf -i
sh: 1: config/ompi_get_version.sh: not found
sh: 1: config/ompi_get_version.sh: not found
sh: 1: config/ompi_get_version.sh: not found
sh: 1: config/ompi_get_version.sh: not found
sh: 1: config/ompi_get_version.sh: not found
sh: 1: config/ompi_get_version.sh: not found
sh: 1: config/ompi_get_version.sh: not found
sh: 1: config/ompi_get_version.sh: not found
sh: 1: config/ompi_get_version.sh: not found
configure.ac:934: error: Could not find project list - rerun autogen.sh without -l
config/ompi_mca.m4:37: OMPI_MCA is expanded from...
configure.ac:934: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

So I think `autogen.sh` is a must.

PS2: I tried `./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/ CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/`. The redefinition error remains.

Comment: Note if you install from a tarball you do not need to run `autogen.sh`. This macro should be automatically set by `configure` if `#include <sys/time.h>` successes. Assuming this header is available, all you need is `configure CPPFLAGS=/path_to_headers`

Comment: You should either run `autogen.sh` or nothing at all. Does `/usr/include/sys/time.h` exist on your system ? You can have a look at `config.log` to figure out why `sys/time.h` cannot be used. If you cannot fix that, then try hacking `opal/include/opal_config.h` and define `HAVE_SYS_TIME_H` macro before running `make` (at your own risk !)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I just updated question description. After adding lots of macros I could compile and install 1.3 without problem, but now I am facing `Address not mapped` from `libpthread.so`....

Comment: You are obviously trying to run an antique version of Open MPI on a (modern) OS that was never tested against. I’d rather suggest you use a supported Open MPI, or use an OS that was supported in the 1.3 days. If not, you have to do the port, and it could be a long road ...